# BeautifulSoup: How to access text in nested Span

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am new to Selenium, and I want to get the string "United States" from a [website](https://www.indeed.com/cmp/Quintal-Contracting/reviews), HTML as shown below:
[image]

I am confused as to how to access the span for country, as there is another span with the exact same class shown below.
[image]

My code:

```
s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
   
CLASS_NAME = "class name"
if (driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-1gzpoyq e1wnkr790")!=None):
        print(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-1gzpoyq e1wnkr790").text)
```

The output printed is `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`, and I'm unsure why that is so.

Comment: I don't think [tag:beautifulsoup] is the right tag for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get the string "United States"

Simply adjust your [`CSS SELECTOR`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) use `.find_element` to select only one / the first element.

Following selector goes for for sibling `<div>` of elemetn with `id="cmp-Select-Location-label"` and selects the `<span>` by its attribute `cmp-Select-Location-label`:

```
...
url = 'https://www.indeed.com/cmp/Quintal-Contracting/reviews'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#cmp-Select-Location-label + div [data-testid="selected-value"]').text
```

*You may think it looks a bit complecated but I recommend to select by more static information like identifiers or HTML structure instead of dynamic classes*

Output:

```
United States
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help, can I ask what is `#cmp-Select-Location-label ` ? I'm new to soup and have yet to see such syntax

Comment: `#` stands for `id` attribute https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors - It is the id of the inputs label.